# Django: Get other field's value from an aggregation query

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```
es = Employee.objects.filter(a few filters).aggregate(Max('Age'))
```

That query is going to give me the oldest employee, so I also want to know some other information associated with that row, for example, the id.

How can I accomplish that? Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more precise in your question ?mixing id (primary key) and aggregate seems to be contradictory (exemple several employee may have the same Max('Age')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need aggregate you only have to order by descending Ages your query set

```
 Employee.objects.filter(a few filters).order_by(['-Age'])[0]
```

Will give you the oldest

Or if you have several old item

```
 age = None
 for x in Employee.objects.filter(a few filters).order_by(['-Age']):
    if age and age != x.Age:
       break
    age = x.Age
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I will have to use aggregate function here.

Comment: Anyway, finally, the problem was solved by using order_by -_-! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `annotate()` instead of `aggregate()`.